# Setpermission on clustered private MSMQ queue

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am trying to allocate additional permissions to a private clustered MSMQ queue.

I found [How to set permissions on MSMQ Cluster queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021440/how-to-set-permissions-on-msmq-cluster-queues) which is the same problem but I can't get it to work.

The key from that article is to set the environment variable:

```
$env:_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ = 'myclusterMSMQ'
```

But what should `myclusterMSMQ` contain?

In my case I have a cluster `MSMQCluster` with two nodes `MSMQNodeA` and `MSMQNodeB`. The queue is in a clustered resource `QueueResource`.

The logical to me is to set it to `QueueResource`, but when I did that, the permission appeared on a queue with the same name on `MSMQNodeA`... this is where I am running my powershell and it is the resource owner - the queue shouldn't be here but during script testing a queue with that name ended up here too.

My code looks like this:

```
$queueUser= "domain\svc-account" 
$queueName=".\private$\log.queue"
$env:_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ = "$queueResource"
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queueName
$queue.SetPermissions($queueuser, [System.Messaging.MessageQueueAccessRights]::WriteMessage)
```

I tried a variation that retrieved the queue using `GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($queueResource)`
but that gave me the error:

> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): The specified
>   format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a
>   direct queue format name cannot be deleted

I am sure that this last method was returning the queue from the `QueueResource` because when I listed all queues, I didn't get any of the other garbage queues that are on `MSMQNodeA`.

How do I set additional queue permissions on a private clustered queue with Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it wasn't working in part because the service account had lost MSMQ admin permissions so it didn't matter what value I used when testing.

The following is the correct syntax:

```
$env:_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ = $QueueResource
```